# Minor change to the delete-vote limit box

Tags: bug, vote-to-delete, wording

When I use all my delete votes, I am presented with this box:

> [image]

---

> You've reached the maximum of `<#>` Deletion votes per day; come back in `<time>`

There are two very minor things we could easily improve here. First, un-capitalize "Deletion". It looks out of place, no other 'voting' type words are capitalized.

Second, since the delete vote limit is calculated based on reputation, let's change the text so that it doesn't sound like everyone has the same limit. So, something like this should work:

> You've reached **your** maximum of `<#>` **deletion** votes per day; come back in `<time>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would mean introducing a new string entirely, we'd have 'Deletion' and 'deletion', since localization. 'Deletion' is actually used in more than a few places.

I like the copy change, though - let me see how many places this would get awkward in other languages, if it's not terrible, we'll probably do it.

Comment: So we have a whole new reason to be scared of capitalization and pluralization bugs.  Forget giant S's.... we now have "localization".

Comment: Eh, not _really_. Jmac just came up with a great way to break plurals out (because they do complicate a whole lot of things) in a way that's manageable. However, I do have access to Jeff's giant S in case things get crazy. _Beginning case_ is a whole other giant S, but you won't break me, I won't resort to what Jeff did ... _yet_.